# Python telegram bot persistence with google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-telegram-bot

I am deploying a **Telegram BOT** using **Python Telegram Bot** library on **Google App Engine flexible environment** and have enabled bot and conversation persistence on this.

The challenge I am facing is, if I update the app and deploy again the conversation has to be restarted since I am unable to copy the persistence file from the previous version of the app.

How do I ensure that the same persistence files are used whenever I deploy a new version of the APP?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing to the `/tmp` directory or storing that file inside App Engine's file system, that is expected to happen.

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-temp-files) for the standard environment explain this as well, and when you're doing a new deploy the instance you were using gets deleted and then you lose your persistence file with the logs of the chat.

You should consider moving the file to Cloud Storage or using any other storage system to save the changes and upload/downlaod the file on a regular basis in order to avoid that.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I now created an API to copy the file to Google cloud storage from App Engine's file system. I am invoking this API just before deploying a new version of my App. And in my App upon startup, it copies the file back to App's file system from GCS.